# Inkscape 0.92 won't open on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, inkscape

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 and installed **Inkscape** from software center and it doesn't strat. Not even opening .svg file already created. (Similar question posted by Vitor Abella on 12.1.2016 with different terminal output.)

On terminal after `inkscape` output was:

```
cannot perform readlinkat() on the mount namespace file descriptor of the init process: Permission denied
```

Need HELP (asap)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you may have launched inkscape as root ?  if so now as yourself you may encounter permission errors since root may own temp files cut by inkscape back when you ran it as root

```
sudo inkscape   #  avoid this ... do NOT do this it may have caused the issue
```

Possible solution would be to uninstall then re-install

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge inkscape  # uninstall

sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

then launch as yourself ... let us know how you get on

Comment: Thank's for quick answer. Try 'sudo inkscape' same output as without 'sudo'. After remove/install as you ask to do, star with 'inkscape'  a lot of lines output in terminal. All lines (27) start with GtkWidget *IconImple::newFull():

Comment: Thank's for quick answer. I am new here and I realy don't know should commnet or answer or what?   I try _sudo inkscape_ same output as without _sudo_. After remove/install as you ask to do, star with _inkscape_  a lot of lines output in terminal.  All lines (27) start with:  GtkWidget *IconImple::newFull(): ... Last line is _Killed_ then Inkscape start. I can do everything except: printing to printer, print to pdf and save as .pdf file.  After executing this commands, screen turn to transparent grey and then Inkscape Quit. BTW I can use printer normaly.

Comment: update your question with a paste of all those 27 lines ...  do not worry about how it appears formatted after you save the question then we'll take a look ... launch inkscape from a terminal as yourself ... then  hightlight all those lines then hit   ctrl-shift-c   to copy then edit question and do the normal ctrl-v to paste

Comment: can you print from other ubuntu applications ?

Comment: yes I can. It's network printer Lexmark e352dn.

Comment: OK so initial issue has been resolved ... I too get many lines like GtkWidget *IconImple::newFull(): lsize != trySize: lsize: 8 try Size: 7 object-visible
      when I launch  inkscape ... I would say ignore those ...  I am able to print to file using inkscape ...   I suggest you create a new question here about printing issue ... or book a ticket at    http://www.inkscapeforum.com/

Comment: OK. So I am not alone. Anyhow thank you for your help.  Good for you. New is that I can print to file but only the size up to aprox. 0.5 Mb. At this moment I don't know what to do. Probably I  will try to install clean Ubuntu 16.04 on other HDD and install Inkscape on them. I stay in touch with you. Good luck!